# Multithreaded Fibonacci Pair Program

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, pthreads, fibonacci

I'm trying to write a program which creates two threads: a "front-end" and "back-end" thread. I want to create a "back-end" thread to iterate and compute pairs of terms from the fibonacci sequence and put them in an array, and a "front-end" thread that will print out the pairs of the array at each iteration.

*"Front-End" Thread - For displaying result of "Back-End" thread operations in each iterations*

*"Back-End" Thread - For calculating and setting an array*

ie. [5, 8], and after an iteration it will contain [13, 21]

I'm struggling to implement the Fibonacci sequence part in a thread and I've made the following progress:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

int fib;
void *front_end(void *ptr);
void *back_end(void *ptr);

int main() {
  pthread_t thread1, thread2;

  int arr[2] = {5,8};
  const int *ptrtoarr;
  ptrtoarr=arr;

  int create1, create2;

  int *s=(int *)(ptrtoarr);
  printf("%d \n", *s);
  ptrtoarr++;
  s = (int *)(ptrtoarr);
  printf("%d \n", *s);
  ptrtoarr--;

  create1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, back_end, &arr);

  if(create1) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n",create1);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  pthread_join(thread1, NULL);

  //pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
}

// front-end thread to be callback for each back-end iteration
void *front_end(void *ptr) {
  int *sum = ptr;
  int i, upper = atoi(ptr);

  if (upper > 0) {
    for (i=0; i<upper; i++){

//Print the fib pairs

    }
  }
  pthread_exit(0);
}

void *back_end(void *ptr) {
  int i, upper = atoi(ptr);
  fib=1;

  if(upper > 0) {
    int pre1 = 0;
    int current;

    //calc fib numbers.....
    if(fib == 1){
      printf("")

    }
  }

}
```

Can someone guide me through how I might approach this?

Comment: That seems like the right idea having the front-end thread be a callback at the end of each iteration with the back-end

Comment: @Logan awesome! I'm having some trouble just actually implementing it

Comment: Threads shouldn't be used for this. Using threads will actually slow down your program. I presume this is an learning exercise? If so, have you learned about `pthread_cond_wait` and `pthread_cond_signal`?

Comment: @ikegami I figured as much! It is an exercise to get familiar with threads, I'm not familiar with implementing those but I assume they are used in multithreading to make sure one thread waits for the other to finish before continuing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your skeleton needs work.

Assuming the following:

```
unsigned n = ...;      // How many to generate.
unsigned n_ready = 2;  // How many are ready to print.
unsigned *fibs = malloc(sizeof(unsigned)*n);
fibs[0] = 0;
fibs[1] = 1;
```

At the core of your back end worker, you will have

```
for (unsigned i=2; i<n; ++i) {
   fibs[i] = fibs[i-2] + fibs[i-1];
   n_ready = i+1;
}
```

At the core of your frontend worker, you will have

```
for (unsigned i=0; i<n; ++i) {
   while (i >= n_ready)
      /* Nothing */;

   printf("%u\n", fibs[i]);
}
```

---

**Problem #1**

You get into problems if a thread tries to read a variable when another is writing to it. Two or more threads reading the same variable at the same time is ok.

The variables used by both threads are `n`, the elements of `fib[]` and `n_ready`.

- `n`:
  Not changed by either thread, so we don't need to control access to it.
- `fib[i]` for `i >= n_ready`:
  Only accessed by the back end worker, so we don't need to control access to these.
- `fib[i]` for `i < n_ready`:
  Only accessed by the frontend worker, so we don't need to control access to these.
- `n_ready`:
  The back end worker could set `n_ready` at any time, and the frontend work could try to read `n_ready` at any time, so we do need to control access to `n_ready`.

Mutex are usually used to ensure that only one thread is accessing a resource (e.g. a variable, group of variables, file handle, etc) at a time.

Our back end worker becomes

```
for (unsigned i=2; i<n; ++i) {
   // The mutex only protects n_ready
   // --nothing else is going to touch fib[i-2] or fib[i-1] or fib[i]--
   // so we don't need to obtain a lock yet.
   fibs[i] = fibs[i-2] + fibs[i-1];

   // We need to access n_ready.
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   n_ready = i+1;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Our frontend worker becomes

```
for (unsigned i=0; i<n; ++i) {
   // We need to access n_ready.
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   while (i >= n_ready) {
      // Allow other thread to gain the lock.
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

      // We need to access n_ready.
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   }

   // The mutex only protects n_ready
   // --nothing is going to change fib[i]--
   // so we can release it now rather than later.
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

   printf("%u\n", fibs[i]);
}
```

---

**Problem #2**

You have a busy loop. In general, this is bad because it means your thread is using 100% doing nothing by waiting. (In this particular case, since `i >= n_ready` is probably already true, this would actually be a good strategy. But let's ignore that.) A thread can sleep until signaled by another thread using condition vars.

Our back end worker becomes

```
for (unsigned i=2; i<n; ++i) {
   // The mutex only protects n_ready
   // --nothing else is going to touch fib[i-2] or fib[i-1] or fib[i]--
   // so we don't need to obtain a lock yet.
   fibs[i] = fibs[i-2] + fibs[i-1];

   // We need to access n_ready.
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   n_ready = i+1;
   // Wake up the other thread if it's blocked.
   pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Our frontend worker becomes

```
for (unsigned i=0; i<n; ++i) {
   // We need to access n_ready.
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   while (i >= n_ready)
      pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);

   // The mutex only protects n_ready
   // --nothing is going to change fib[i]--
   // so we can release it now rather than later.
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

   printf("%u\n", fibs[i]);
}
```

Always call `pthread_cond_wait` on a locked mutex. It will unlock the mutex when it's called, and it will lock it before returning. This allows the other thread to obtain the mutex in order to change `n_ready`.

---

Complete code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)


// To control access to n_ready.
static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static unsigned n_ready = 0;  // How many are ready to print.

static unsigned n;  // How many to generate.
static unsigned *fibs = NULL;


static void *back_worker(void *unused) {
   UNUSED(unused);

   fibs[0] = 0;
   fibs[1] = 1;

   // We need to access n_ready.
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   n_ready = 2;
   // Wake up the other thread if it's blocked.
   pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

   for (unsigned i=2; i<n; ++i) {
      // The mutex only protects n_ready
      // --nothing is going to touch fib[i]--
      // so we don't need to obtain a lock yet.
      fibs[i] = fibs[i-2] + fibs[i-1];

      // We need to access n_ready.
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      n_ready = i+1;
      // Wake up the other thread if it's blocked.
      pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   }

   return NULL;
}


static void *front_worker(void *unused) {
   UNUSED(unused);

   for (unsigned i=0; i<n; ++i) {
      // We need to access n_ready.
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      while (i >= n_ready)
         pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);

      // The mutex only protects n_ready
      // --nothing is going to change fib[i]--
      // so we can release it now rather than later.
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

      printf("%u\n", fibs[i]);
   }

   return NULL;
}


int main(void) {
   n = 20;  // How many to generate.

   fibs = malloc(sizeof(unsigned) * n);

   pthread_t back_thread;
   if (errno = pthread_create(&back_thread, NULL, back_worker, NULL)) {
      perror(NULL);
      exit(1);
   }

   pthread_t front_thread;
   if (errno = pthread_create(&front_thread, NULL, front_worker, NULL)) {
      perror(NULL);
      exit(1);
   }

   pthread_join(back_thread, NULL);
   pthread_join(front_thread, NULL);

   pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
   pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
   free(fibs);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic a.c -o a -lpthread && a
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
```

---

**Suggestion for an exercise to apply the above**

Create a pool of workers that print out the numbers placed into a queue. The output doesn't need to be in order.

The worker function is already written for you. **You may not change the `main` or `worker` functions.** I've even created the queue for you. You simply have to make it thread safe by modifying `Queue_enqueue`, `Queue_dequeue` and `Queue_done` functions. **These are the only functions you may change.**

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_WORKERS 4
#define QUEUE_SIZE 10
#define NUM_ITEMS 40

typedef struct {
   pthread_mutex_t mutex;
   pthread_cond_t cond;
   int done;
   int empty;
   int full;
   size_t max;
   size_t next_insert;
   size_t next_read;
   unsigned *buf;
} Queue;

static void Queue_init(Queue* q, size_t max) {
   pthread_mutex_init(&(q->mutex), NULL);
   pthread_cond_init(&(q->cond), NULL);
   q->done = 0;
   q->empty = 1;
   q->full = 0;
   q->max = max;
   q->next_insert = 0;
   q->next_read = 0;
   q->buf = malloc(sizeof(unsigned)*max);
}

static void Queue_destroy(Queue *q) {
   free(q->buf);
   pthread_cond_destroy(&(q->cond));
   pthread_mutex_destroy(&(q->mutex));
}

static void Queue_done(Queue *q) {
   q->done = 1;
}

// Returns the oldest item from the queue (via a parameter) and returns 1.
// If the queue is empty and done, returns 0.
// If the queue is empty and not done, waits until that changes.
static int Queue_dequeue(Queue *q, unsigned *i) {
   while (q->empty && !q->done) {
   }

   if (q->empty) {
      // We are completely done.
      return 0;
   } else {
      *i = q->buf[ q->next_read ];
      q->next_read = ( q->next_read + 1 ) % q->max;
      q->empty = q->next_read == q->next_insert;
      q->full = 0;
      return 1;
   }
}

// Adds the argument to the queue.
// If the queue is full, waits until that changes.
static void Queue_enqueue(Queue *q, unsigned i) {
   while (q->full && !q->done) {
   }

   if (q->done) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: Attempted to add item to \"done\" queue.\n");
      return;
   }

   q->buf[q->next_insert] = i;
   q->next_insert = ( q->next_insert + 1 ) % q->max;
   q->empty = 0;
   q->full = q->next_insert == q->next_read;
}

static int msleep(long msec) {
   struct timespec ts;
   int res;

   if (msec < 0) {
       errno = EINVAL;
       return -1;
   }

   ts.tv_sec = msec / 1000;
   ts.tv_nsec = (msec % 1000) * 1000000;

    do {
       res = nanosleep(&ts, &ts);
    } while (res && errno == EINTR);

    return res;
}

// Protects access to stdout.
static pthread_mutex_t stdout_mutex;

static Queue q;

static void *worker(void *worker_id_) {
   uintptr_t worker_id = (uintptr_t)worker_id_;

   unsigned int seed = worker_id;  // Whatever.

   unsigned i;
   while (Queue_dequeue(&q, &i)) {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&stdout_mutex);
      printf("[%" PRIuPTR "] Dequeued %u\n", worker_id, i);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdout_mutex);

      // msleep( rand_r(&seed) % 1000 + 1000 );  // Simulate a 1 to 2s load.

      pthread_mutex_lock(&stdout_mutex);
      printf("[%" PRIuPTR "]    Finished processing %u\n", worker_id, i);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdout_mutex);
   }

   return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
   Queue_init(&q, QUEUE_SIZE);

   pthread_t workers[NUM_WORKERS];
   for (uintptr_t i=0; i<NUM_WORKERS; ++i) {
      if (errno = pthread_create(&(workers[i]), NULL, worker, (void*)i)) {
         perror(NULL);
         exit(1);
      }
   }

   for (unsigned i=0; i<NUM_ITEMS; ++i) {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&stdout_mutex);
      printf("[x] Enqueuing %u...\n", i);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdout_mutex);

      Queue_enqueue(&q, i);

      pthread_mutex_lock(&stdout_mutex);
      printf("[x]    Enqueued %u.\n", i);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdout_mutex);
   }

   Queue_done(&q);
   pthread_mutex_lock(&stdout_mutex);
   printf("[x] Called done.\n");
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdout_mutex);

   for (unsigned i=0; i<NUM_WORKERS; ++i)
      pthread_join(workers[i], NULL);

   Queue_destroy(&q);
   pthread_mutex_destroy(&stdout_mutex);
   return 0;
}
```

If you have questions about this, feel free to post a link to the question as a comment to this answer.

---

**Solution to suggested excercise:**

```
static void Queue_done(Queue *q) {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&(q->mutex));
   q->done = 1;
   pthread_cond_signal(&(q->cond));
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&(q->mutex));
}

// Returns the oldest item from the queue (via a parameter) and returns 1.
// If the queue is empty and done, returns 0.
// If the queue is empty and not done, waits until that changes.
static int Queue_dequeue(Queue *q, unsigned *i) {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&(q->mutex));
   while (q->empty && !q->done)
      pthread_cond_wait(&(q->cond), &(q->mutex));

   int dequeued;
   if (q->empty) {
      // We are completely done.
      dequeued = 0;
   } else {
      *i = q->buf[ q->next_read ];
      q->next_read = ( q->next_read + 1 ) % q->max;
      q->empty = q->next_read == q->next_insert;
      q->full = 0;
      dequeued = 1;
   }

   pthread_cond_signal(&(q->cond));
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&(q->mutex));
   return dequeued;
}

// Adds the argument to the queue.
// If the queue is full, waits until that changes.
static void Queue_enqueue(Queue *q, unsigned i) {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&(q->mutex));
   while (q->full && !q->done)
      pthread_cond_wait(&(q->cond), &(q->mutex));

   if (q->done) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: Attempted to add item to \"done\" queue.\n");
   } else {
      q->buf[q->next_insert] = i;
      q->next_insert = ( q->next_insert + 1 ) % q->max;
      q->empty = 0;
      q->full = q->next_insert == q->next_read;
   }

   pthread_cond_signal(&(q->cond));
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&(q->mutex));
}
```

Comment: I have never been so grateful in all my life, this is a fantastic explanation of how this all works! Thank you so much for walking me through this so clearly and organized, seeing it all put together in code makes a lot of sense, I can't emphasize how valuable it is for a learner like myself!

Comment: @coderboy99 There are genuinely warm and helpful people in this platform as ikegami, you're welcome to the place ;)

Comment: I've added an exercise for you at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @ikegami I am seriously very excited to try this!! I can't thank you enough for how helpful this all is! And I know I'll feel much more comfortable with it as a result

Comment: I've added the solution the suggested exercise to my answer.